# zend framework update db not work

Tags: database, zend-framework, frameworks

I wanna update a table by using this update commands but nothing happend. anybody knows why ?!

```
$db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
$updateData = array(
'user_type' => 0
);
$updateWhere = array(
'username = ?' => 'admin'
);
$res = $db->update('phpbb3_users', $updateData, $updateWhere);
```

Comment: I write this part of code in one of my IndexAction() of controllers. it return int(0) and do nothing

Comment: Oh, I was checking wrong DB! it is working :P !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this code is working for me to update

```
$updateData = array(
'user_type' => 0
);
        $updateWhere = array(
'username' => 'admin'
);
```

**or**

```
  $updateWhere = "username = 'admin'";  
            $db->update('phpbb3_users', $updateData, $updateWhere);
```

hope it will sure solve your issue